# POWERSHELL; Recursive Get-Member for Com Object

Tags: powershell

I have a statement "New-Object -com Indesign.Application.Cs5  | Get-Member"
It works as expected for the top level.

How would one recurse the entire object tree and output results in a readable/spreadsheet format (if possible).

Answer (score 5):

The built-in way to do this is use Format-Custom like so:

```
Get-Process -id $pid | Format-Custom -Property * -Depth 4
```

If you want to recurse deeper I think you need to bump up the default value of $FormatEnumerationLimit (defaults to 4).  Be careful though, I used to bump this to 100 and in certain cases when using fc, PowerShell would seem to hang.  It was either caught in a cycle (probably not) or the operation was just going to take longer than I was willing to wait.  BTW the short version of the above:

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit = 10
gps -id $pid | fc * -dep 10
```

Comment: Thanks Keith, I'm NOT to PowerShell saavy as yet, Could you please layout the complete code using "Indesign.Application.Cs5" as the COM object.

Thanks again

Comment: Try this: `New-Object -com Indesign.Application.Cs5 | Format-Custom * -Depth 2`.  Adjust depth as desired but note that the time required is likely to increase significantly with more depth.